# Understand values for Landsat 8 surface reflectance image

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat-8, reflectance

What do the numbers represent when you download an image, in my case Landsat 8 OLI TIRS surface reflectance.

Are they DN numbers or reflectance values?

If the image is not surface reflectance product, do those numbers still mean the same?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Please edit your question to include a single, focused question.

Answer (score 1):

It is reflectance value but has been stored in native integer raster format by multiply it with 10000. So divide by 10000 for the surface reflectance unit.